# TFS 2015 not able to queue build using TFS2010 controller

Tags: build, tfs-2015

we have upgraded from TFS2010 to TFS2015.
And connected  the TFS2010 XAML build controller to TFS2015.
when we try to queue the build , we are not able to see the build controller in the drop down of build controller.
we could see that the Build controller registered and in running state.
I am getting error **"TF900560: Could not start build: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
"**

Comment: we are not able to see the build controller in the drop down of build definition. few users with Project administrator privileges are able to see the controller and queue the build but not contributors group.

Comment: Can the users with Project administrator privileges run the build normally?

Answer (score 1):

This issue was caused because we have used the TFS controller which is cloned from the current production. Therefore, it is always suggested to reconfigure the build controller rather than using a cloned one.

Answer (score 0):

Please check below items to narrow down the issue:

- Check your TFS server an agent server to make sure the machines are
  **not running out of disk space**. In this case, you can try clearing up some space on the servers.
- Change the agent service account as another user account which has
  admin privileges.
- Restart the TFS and Agent servers.

---

**UPDATE1:**

Seems it should be the permission issue, just try to compare the permissions of `Contributors` and `Project Administrators` groups , then set the correct permission for `Contributors` group.

**You can also try to clean the caches for your IE or change another browser even client to check that again.**

---

**UPDATE2:**

As you mentioned in below comments "`few users from same contributors group are able to queue the build`".

So you can compare the permission settings between the vaild and invalid users in Contributors group. Then debug accrodingly. (Switch to **Users** tab in below screenshot --> Select the specific user to check the permission settings)

[image]

Comment: Users with Project Administrators are able to run the build without issue.What i have observed users with Contributors group are able to see the Build Controller and able to queue the build  from  Team explorer in the Visual Studio , but users who tried from the Web Portal URL they are not able to see the build controller while queuing the build . Is there a difference from build queue from Team Explorer in Visual Studio against WebPortal from Internet explorer?

Comment: @MohanKrishna Nothing difference, I can see the build controller in both Team Explorer in VS and Web portal. Seems it's the permission issue with the user account. You can compare the permissions of `Contributors` and `Project Administrators` groups , then set the correct permission for Contributors group. See the updated answer.

Comment: Thanks Andy for all that information, i will confirm if that helped. on the Other note as i said , few users from same contributors group are able to queue the build , that is something confusion to change on the permissions, but these permissions also should have migrated as part of TFS2010 to TFS2015 upgrade right ? as they never had this issue in TFS2010

Comment: @MohanKrishna Yeah, just have a try, actually there's an permission related issue in previous TFS, somthing like mentioned in [this blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/bharry/2013/01/04/bugs-in-tfs-update-1/). Besides, as you said "`few users from same contributors group are able to queue the build`", So you can compare the permission settings between the vaild and invalid users in Contributors group. Then debug accrodingly.

Comment: Thanks for the hint Andy, i will check further in terms of permissions

Comment: @MohanKrishna Yeah, just have a check with that. Any update please freely post here :)

Comment: Andy ,no luck after validating the user privileges. users who are able to queue, and few who are not able to queue are present only in the contributors group, not member of any other groups. the difference i see , who are able to queue could see Build controller name in the definition, and there is no controller name  displayed for those who are not able to queue.